# Angular Unhandled Exception after ng s

Tags: angular, npm

Why I receive that error after ng s command.

My package.json

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.9",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.9",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.9",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
    "@nexgis/geweb-interfaces-topnav-menu": "0.0.7",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "ang-jsoneditor": "1.10.4",
    "bootstrap": "4.5.3",
    "geostyler-sld-parser": "2.1.0",
    "hamburgers": "1.1.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "js-base64": "3.6.0",
    "jsoneditor": "9.1.7",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.0.9",
    "@types/node": "~14.14.21",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~6.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~9.1.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
    "typescript": "~4.1.3"
  }
}
```

This is the exception:

> ```
> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
> Require stack:
>
> - C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
> - C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
> - C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
> - C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
> - C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
> - C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
> - C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
> - C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
> - C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
> - C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
> - C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
> See "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-ijkLHO\angular-errors.log" for further details.
> ```

My npm @angular/cli -v
6.14.11.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` in the directory of the `package.json`? Did it run without errors? The `angular-devkit` doesn't seem to be available in the `node_modules` however it is listend in the `package.json`.

Comment: Try `npm install` then `ng update` and finally `npm update`.